# Error in Instagram Basic display API: Matching code was not found or was already used

Tags: php, api, token, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to access the **ACCESS_TOKEN**  from [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions). I success full get the code as mentioned below and now I am trying to pass this `$_GET['code']` to `accesstoken()` but getting no responce(error).

```
 //sample request demo (string(240))  
https://www. mysite.org/dashboard.php?code=AQAWTCkmCLVYUJddAqjcNvhh_BZDJg-68vSK1bun3KdNp3nbLdcjexCncu_LvPtk4jY5bJTCXe4vJ9yldmBsUZzE0heDtkhhd--SrPlCer0Lq5J25qZ_X9OBQ5AokmxCum4kz6kgqN1ilq6ZLT1m84mIJ0_hhLVKXwaPTprUXgRtmm1Gat5NbdbhtuXjOqMgD9yFfe94QVsV-aQ7CwKpAtPTrT9_nSUVDVedF0JhbqvWbQ#_
```

Here below I just removed the `#_` at the end of the `$_GET['code']` and pass it on to the function.

```
$object = new instaAPI();
$code = trim($_GET['code'], "#_"); //removed the tralling #_ from the end.
$access = $object->accesstoken(APP_ID, REDIRECT_URI, APP_SECRET, $code); //calling
echo $access['access_token']; // blank
```

**Curl function**

```
class instaAPI
{
    public function accesstoken($app_id, $redirect_uri, $app_secret, $cod)
    {
      $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';


      $curl_post = 'app_id='.$app_id. '&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri.'&app_secret='.$app_secret.'&code='.$cod.'grant_type=authorization_code';
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post);

      $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
      $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      curl_close($ch);
      if($http_code !== 200)            
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to receieve access token'.'IG_ERROR_TYPE:'.$data['error_type'].'CODE:'.$data['code'].'MESSAGE'.$data['error_message']);


      return $data;

    } 


}
```

**Response OR Json Response**

```
Error: Failed to receive access token 

IG_ERROR_TYPE: OAuthException 
CODE:400
MESSAGE: Matching code was not found or was already used
```

or

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used"
}
```

I am stuck at this point, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably start by applying proper URL-encoding to the parameter values in your API request.

Comment: `$code = trim($_GET['code'], "#_"); //removed the tralling #_ from the end.` – absolutely unnecessary of course, there never was any `#_` at the end of `$_GET['code']`

Comment: $_GET['code'] output is https://www. mysite.org/dashboard.php?code=AQAWTCkmCLVYUJddAqjcNvhh_BZDJg-68vSK1bun3KdNp3nbLdcjexCncu_LvPtk4jY5bJTCXe4vJ9yldmBsUZzE0heDtkhhd--SrPlCer0Lq5J25qZ_X9OBQ5AokmxCum4kz6kgqN1ilq6ZLT1m84mIJ0_hhLVKXwaPTprUXgRtmm1Gat5NbdbhtuXjOqMgD9yFfe94QVsV-aQ7CwKpAtPTrT9_nSUVDVedF0JhbqvWbQ#_

Comment: see at the end of ....WbQ#_

Comment: `#_` is part of the URL, but it is not part of the value of the parameter `code`. (That’s how URLs _work_ - `#` starts the _fragment_ portion.)

Comment: yep, I know that is why I removed it. because in the documentation they said to remove the trailing #_  at the end of the code, that's what I do: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions

Comment: There _is_ nothing to remove, `$_GET['code']` will not contain this trailing `#_` in the first place, _because_ it is not part of that parameter’s value to begin with. It does not even get send to the server in the first place by most clients.

Answer (score 1):

Change from "$cod" to "$code" in this line:

```
public function accesstoken($app_id, $redirect_uri, $app_secret, $cod)
```

and:

```
 $curl_post = 'app_id='.$app_id. '&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri.'&app_secret='.$app_secret.'&code='.$cod.'grant_type=authorization_code';
```

Comment: Thanks, but its dosn't matter whatever you define here

Comment: It doesn't but you're using "$code" above those 2 lines.  Most likely, you're not sending Instagram a code at all because "$cod" is an undefined variable.